# Scatter plot; intervals between value should be 0

Tags: excel

I have a long data table filled with timestamps and a field that has info about that timestamp in the following format

```
date        time      comp/H
---------- ----- ----------------------
2019-09-10 07:01 13640,416015625
2019-09-10 07:02 8970,3193359375
2019-09-10 07:03 6105,4990234375
2019-09-10 07:04 7189,77880859375
2019-09-10 07:08 2266,73657226563
2019-09-10 07:57 163,527984619141
```

i would like to make a time series based scatter plot, although i want the plot to drop to 0 for the time intervals between these records. At the moment the intervals are connected with a line, where they should drop to 0 when there's an empty interval (for example in this case, between 7:04-7:08 the graph should drop to 0)

Just to be clear, i don't have actual 0 values for every minute in my dataset, i only have data for the minutes which DOES have an object in the comp/h

i would like to group my data per minute so that each record in a minute gets assigned to that minute

How do i do this?

Comment: The easiest way I know of would be to extend this dataset or create a separate dataset that cotains the 0 values and use that as the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony Lemaitre said, an easy way would be a separate dataset with all times. There you could check if a time exists in your original data (e.g. using MATCH-function) and copy the value or setting it to zero otherwise. This could look something like:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$8,0),6)),0)
```

Here A1 contains the time you want to search for, $B$1:$B$8 would be the column with your time stamps in your dataset and 6 would be the column where to look for comp/H if A1 was found.

By using a line going to zero in a diagram, take note you indicate, that the value really is zero (and not just missing data). If that's not what you want, you could consider to just use scatter plot without a line. Or to split your line in several disconnected lines (more complicated).